# Swift - How can I select multiple rows in tableview without segue

Tags: swift, tableview

My development environment is swift3, xcode8.
I'm making a list app like Apple's message app.
When I select the list in the table view, I go to the detail page (through the seg) and now I want to implement multiple delete functions, but there's a problem. When I edit mode, I can see the selection window, but if I select that selection window, just go to the detail page.

Maybe before going to the detail page through Seg. I think I should make it a multiple choice. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you conform something like below code;

```
class TableviewController:UITableViewController{
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var isMultipleSelectionActive = false
    var selectedItems: [String: Bool] = [:]
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
    tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedItem = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    //add to selectedItems
    selectedItems[selectedItem] = true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedItem = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    // remove from selectedItems
    selectedItems[selectedItem] = nil
}

func getStatusOfSelectedItems() {
    for item in selectedItems {
        println(item)
    }
}

//You should override shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier and return false if isMultipleSelectionActive is true

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String?, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if let identifierName = identifier {
        if identifierName == "NameOfYourSegueIdentifier" {
             if isMultipleSelectionActive {
                  return false
             }
        }
    }
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
However, this code did not find the source I needed.
Multiple selection works well only if segue is not working.

Is there any way to not go to segue in multi-selection in edit mode?

Comment: how can i show you my code ? I don't know well because I'm a beginner.. The segue was created by dragging the cell from the storyboard with the control + left mouse button, dragging it to the detail page, and then selecting show.

Comment: Cool!! i got you, i thought you may have written code for it!! @HoonyB

Comment: @HoonyB make sure you update isMultipleSelectionActive variable as per your need!!

Comment: thank you brother. I solved this problem!
Sorry, I did not see the bottom of the sauce.
What I wanted to know was that function.

Answer (score 0):

This code used to select the multiple row

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    var lastSelectedIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: -1, inSection: 0)

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel!.text = "row: \(indexPath.row)"

        if cell.selected
        {
            cell.selected = false
            if cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
            {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
            }
            else
            {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
            }
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        if cell!.selected
        {
            cell!.selected = false
            if cell!.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
            {
                cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
            }
            else
            {
                cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But my problem is that if I check in edit mode,
It is not checked but goes to the detail page by segue operation of the cell.
I would like to check it in edit state, not segue operation

If I compile without segue
Multiple selection works well.